# How to reset the maintenance counter of the intermediate transfer unit of a Konica Minolta magicolor 2430DL?

Tags: printer, cleaning

I've replaced the transfer belt unit of a Konica Minolta magicolor 2430DL and the instructions that came with the piece say that I need to "reset the maintenance counter of the Intermediate Transfer Unit", but provides no specific instructions on how to do so and printer documentation doesn't have anything about it as far as I could find.

How do I reset this maintenance counter?

Comment: I assume only a qualified service tech can do this.

Comment: Contact Konica tech support.